# Using ffmpeg (or similar) to print detailed h264 information

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, analysis

I have some h264 video in mpeg transport stream, and I suspect at certain points in the video it switches from 1080i/50Hz to 1080p/25Hz. I'd like to prove that using some video analysis tool. Can ffmpeg (or similar) print out such detailed decoding info? I've tried ffmpeg setting "-loglevel debug" but it prints no more info about the actual decoding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ffprobe` is a far easier solution and is included with FFmpeg:

```
$ ffprobe -show_frames -i input.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it. In the end I put a few printfs into ffmpeg source to get the info I needed.

Comment: vlc -vv (ultra verbose) is an invaluable tool for these kind of situations

Comment: @arashkordi VLC uses FFmpeg so using ffprobe is still better.